# Incorrect name and broken image for site at SEDE

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Over at [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), on the list of sites, [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/) is still listed as "Cognitive Sciences" and the image is scrambled:

[image]

Can we fix that?